# When one aside is open close the others

Tags: jquery, class, click

I have this code:

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('nav ul li').click(function () {
          $('aside.' + this.className).toggleClass('opened');
       });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li class="index">Home</li>
    <li class="index2">some text</li>
</ul>
  </nav>

  <aside class="index">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </aside>

  <aside class="index2">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2</p>
  </aside>
```

Now I want that when I open One Aside all the others to be closed ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('aside').not('.' + this.className).removeClass('opened');
$('aside.' + this.className).toggleClass('opened');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nav ul li').click(function () {
      $('aside').removeClass('opened');
      //just do the 1st one at index `0`
      $('aside.' + this.className).eq(0).toggleClass('opened'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Won't `.toggleClass` end up always adding the class in that case?

Comment: @ExplosionPills the op wants to add the class like he has in the OP but he wants remove that class from all the ones that were already opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('aside').click(function(){
    $('aside').not(this).removeClass('opened');
});
```

Comment: it's good but now I cannot close all... one must stay open.. that is not good.